# Upgrading from PostgreSQL 9.6.11 to 10.7 gives strange SETVAL() statements

Tags: amazon-rds

We've upgraded our PostgreSQL running on AWS RDS from 9.6.11 to 10.7 to prepare for upgrading to Aurora Serverless (which requires 10.7).
After upgrading however we get strange behavior when INSERTING data pointing to Sequences that don't exist in the database.

We create a new DB with 9.6.11 and restored the snapshot and that is working again so clearly there is something changed/broken in 10.7.

Here's a snippet from the logs:

```
2019-10-07 07:23:30 UTC:xxx(35000):xxx@db:[24429]:ERROR:  syntax error at or near "c23da7" at character 48
2019-10-07 07:23:30 UTC:xxx(35000):xxx@db:[24429]:STATEMENT:  SELECT setval('"public"."process_uuid_seq"', 79c23da7-4451-4330-b2f0-5859e0b36887, true)
2019-10-07 07:23:30 UTC:xxx(35000):xxx@db:[24429]:LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
2019-10-07 07:25:43 UTC:xxx(35096):xxx@db:[26450]:ERROR:  syntax error at or near "ef9471bf52f" at character 71
2019-10-07 07:25:43 UTC:xxx(35096):xxx@db:[26450]:STATEMENT:  SELECT setval('"public"."process_uuid_seq"', fc1133b6-c857-4899-8196-3ef9471bf52f, true)
```

`"public"."process_uuid_seq"` is not an object in the database that we have created.
There are other "strange" Sequences failing for other INSERT's e.g. `"public"."invoice_total_sum_seq"` which we can't find any reference to in teh code or database...

Where does these sequences come from and how can we adopt/migrate so that 10.7 would be working?

Comment: These statements would cause a syntax error in PostgreSQL. It must be some hack by Amazon. This is unrelated to PostgreSQL.

Comment: Thanks! I've now raised a support ticket with AWS and reported the same there. I'll post back with response fromt hem (when/if I get one)!